# Getting referrer and tracking conversions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, logging, analytics

I'm trying to create a mini analytics page like the one shown on the image below. It's a marketplace and each user has their analytics page with a graph. I've been able to get the views and referrer but my problem is how to go about doing the conversion part.
[image]
In my item show action i have something like this:

```
def show
    @item = Item.find_by_rand_no params[:number]
    if current_user && current_user.id != @item.owner_id
      @item.views.create(item_id: @item.id, ip_address: request.remote_ip, owner_id:  @item.owner_id, referrer: request.env["HTTP_REFERER"])
    end
end
```

How do i track the ones that actually bought something so i can get a conversion rate? 
Ps: A user may land on the page then click on another item and buy that instead. I also want to be able to account for that scenario.
Thanks

Comment: did you try storing information in the user session?

Comment: Oh ok, you mean store the referrer in the user's session?

Comment: for example. classical user tracking systems store some identifier in a tracking cookie http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Tracking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your application controller create a before filter e.g. `before_filter :save_referrer`

```
def save_referrer
   unless session['referrer']
      session['referrer'] = request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] || 'none'
   end
end
```

When a user buys an item you can save the referrer in a field either in the order table or create a separate table for referrals which i think is the better option, you can store views for each referrer by counter caching that column. You can also use first_or_create if you don't want to have to group by the referrer column and so on, it's up to you. Anyway you get conversion like this;

```
Conversion = (Sales/Number of unique views for a referrer) * 100
```